# get time in user timezone angular 5 + ngx-moment

Tags: angular, angular2-moment

I have response from server:

```
dateCreated = "2019-02-06T14:43:50+03:00"
```

And on UI I have:

```
{{ dateCreated | amTimeAgo }}
```

I want to see in result `1 hour ago`, but I see `4 hours ago`.

What other pipe should I add here or how can I resolve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I used this:

```
{{ OccurredOn | amFromUtc | amDateFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss a' | amTimeAgo }}
```